# Check in checkbox missing when scrolling up/down

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone i have a problem in my application. The check in my check box, once i check the check box and scroll it down/up the check is gone, i didn't know how that happen. can anyone help me with this? THANKS for the help :)
HERE IS MY CODE:

```
public class TaskKiller extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TaskKillerActivity";
    TaskListAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;

    private List<TaskObject> getTasksToKill() {
        List<TaskObject> tol = new ArrayList<TaskObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TaskObject to = adapter.getItem(i);
            if (to.isToKill()) {
                tol.add(to);
            }
        }

        return tol;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    public void loadRunningProcesses() {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appinfolist = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();

        Log.d(TAG, "AppInfoList Size: " + appinfolist.size());

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : appinfolist) {
            TaskObject runningtask = new TaskObject();
            runningtask.setPid(runningAppProcessInfo.pid);
            runningtask.setProcessName(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
            adapter.addTask(runningtask);
        }
    }

    class TaskObject {
        int pid;
        String processName;
        private boolean toKill;

        public int getPid() {
            return pid;
        }

        public void setPid(int pid) {
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public String getProcessName() {
            return processName;
        }

        public void setProcessName(String processName) {
            this.processName = processName;
        }

        public boolean isToKill() {
            return toKill;
        }

        public void setToKill(boolean toKill) {
            this.toKill = toKill;
        }

    }

    class TaskListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final String TAG = "TaskListAdapter";

        ArrayList<TaskObject> list;
        Context context;

        public TaskListAdapter(Context context) {
            Log.d(TAG, "created new task list adapter");
            this.context = context;
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<TaskKiller.TaskObject>();
            }
        }

        public void addTask(TaskObject taskObject) {
            list.add(taskObject);
        }

        public void clearTasks() {
            list.clear();
            Log.d(TAG, "list size:" + list.size());
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public TaskObject getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
            TextView textPid = new TextView(context);
            textPid.setId(222222);
            textPid.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getPid()));

            TextView textName = new TextView(context);
            textName.setId(333333);
            textName.setText(getItem(position).getProcessName());

            CheckBox chckKill = new CheckBox(context);
            chckKill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // is chkIos checked?
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        getItem(position).setToKill(true);
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you aren't using the item's toKill status into the Checkbox. When you scroll, it get's redrawn with getView - and is reset to empty.

add

```
chckKill.setChecked( ((TaskObject) getItem(position) ).isToKill());
```

after the constructor.

Comment: there is an error _Cannot cast from boolean to TaskKiller.TaskObject_. and where will i place this code? because i place it after this code? CheckBox chckKill = new CheckBox(context); am i right

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus might've been missing a (. Try again. And yes, add that after the CheckBox.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it work. :) Can i ask question again. How about i what a name only to appear not the package name? because here in my code it is a package name that appear for ex: _com.google.android_ what i want is name only like _google_ or _tomcat_

Comment: sir i have a problem again sir. when i unchecked the check box and i scroll it up/down the check was there again. thanks for the help again.

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus your problem is you're only handling the case where it's unchecked, and becomes checked. You need to handle the case where it was checked, and became unchecked. if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        getItem(position).setToKill(true);
                    }
else{ getItem(position).setToKill(false); }

Comment: oh it works sir. thanks for the help again. :)) can i ask another question again to you sir?

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus sure, if it's too complicated to be in a comment you might want to make a new question thread though

Comment: is it possible that i can get the percentage of battery consumption of each running application? if so? how sir? THANKS AGAIN :))

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus I have no idea. You should post a new question

Comment: i already post this question but they closed it because i didn't know that it is restricted here to post, not same question, but same explanation and detail. :)) and no one answer my question about this. i don't know why. anyway how about sir the battery charging animation? i mean when charging the battery.